# No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Using Geoserver + Openlayers

Tags: openlayers-2, geoserver, request, http-headers

This is my code to open a WFS layer from geoserver:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang='en'>
<head>
 <meta charset='utf-8' />
 <title>My OpenLayers Map</title>
 <script type='text/javascript' src='OpenLayers.js'></script>
 <script type='text/javascript'>

 //Variável map
 var map;

 //Função a ser chamada para criar o mapa na leitura da página
 function init() {

 // A classe Map espera dois argumentos "map_element" que o ID do elemento HTLML geralmente uma DIV e opções de mapa {key:value}
 map = new OpenLayers.Map('map_element', {}); 

 //Camada WFS
 var wfs_layer = new OpenLayers.Layer.Vector(
    "Routes",
    {
        strategies: [new OpenLayers.Strategy.Fixed()]
        ,projection: new OpenLayers.Projection ("EPSG:900913")
        ,protocol: new OpenLayers.Protocol.WFS({

            version:"1.1.0",
            url:"http://localhost:8080/geoserver/wfs",
            featurePrefix: 'spatial',
            featureType: "spatial:onibus",
            featureNS:"http://spatial/application/webGIS",
            geometryName: "geom"
        })
    }

    );

 //Adicionar as camadas ao mapa
 map.addLayers([
    wfs_layer]);

 //Camada de controle que vai mostrar as camadas no mapa
 map.addControl(new OpenLayers.Control.LayerSwitcher({}));

 //Verifica se o mapa tem um ponto central e o extende a sua extensão máxima
 if(!map.getCenter()){
 map.zoomToMaxExtent();

 }
 }

 </script>
</head>

<body onload='init();'> <!-- Chama a função js init() --> 

<!--Elemento HTML onde o mapa é exibido -->
 <div id='map_element' style='width: 1000px; height: 900px;'>
 </div>

</body>
</html>
```

The page is in www folder of geoserver, when I run it gives the error:

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://localhost:8080/geoserver/wfs. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access.
```

I searched but did not quite understand because I am excutando locally. 
Can someone explain to me more clearly why this error? 
How should I solve it?

This error only occurs in Chrome. 
Firefox will not appear on the map, but the console is:

```
    file:///C:/Program%20Files/GeoServer%202.4.5/data_dir/www/OpenLayers.js
file:///C:/Program%20Files/GeoServer%202.4.5/data_dir/www/theme/default/style.css
file:///C:/Program%20Files/GeoServer%202.4.5/data_dir/www/img/layer-switcher-maximize.png
file:///C:/Program%20Files/GeoServer%202.4.5/data_dir/www/img/layer-switcher-minimize.png
OPTIONS http://localhost:8080/geoserver/wfs
```

Comment: Firstly, do not run the application from the file system. Use a WebServer to host your HTML+JS files. Secondly, this answer might help you: http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/27729/when-do-i-need-to-use-a-proxy-with-openlayers/86386#86386

Comment: Sorry, you mean for me to install GeoServer on Tomcat for example?

Comment: Where is your JavaScript code currently located? How are you accessing it in your browser? What address do you see in address bar of the browser? If you access the htm and Javascript from the file system, instead of from a webserver, you will run into several issues. Mainly for you, won't be able to host a proxy that can do cross domain requests.

Comment: My javascript code is in the www folder GeoServer, now accessed by http://localhost:8080/geoserver/www/example_wfs_localhost.html browser 

There were no error in the Chrome console but did not show the map. 
Appeared the message XHR finished loading: POST "http://localhost:8080/geoserver/wfs". OpenLayers.js: 553 
b.send OpenLayers.js: 553 
(anonymous function) 

This means that my request was answered? But did not draw the map.